# Derivative of a matrix and a vector

Tags: vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

If I have this formula in a project:
$(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C})_r^T(\mathbf{A}_i\mathbf{B})^T$,

where $\mathbf{A}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$, $\mathbf{B}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times N}$,$\mathbf{C}\in\mathbb{R}^{N\times R}$, $\mathbf{A}_i\in\mathbb{R}^{1\times N}$ means the $i$-th row of $\mathbf{A}$, $(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C})_r$ means the $r$-th column of $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}$.

I want to calculate the derivation respect to $\mathbf{A}_i$. How can I solve it?

Comment: Please edit the question to explain why you’ve asked this and what your thoughts are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{e_k\}$ denote the standard basis vectors and define the variables
$$\eqalign{
\def\p{F_{ri}}
\def\Sk{\sum_{k=1}^n\:}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
X &= A^T \\
x_i &= Xe_i \,\equiv\, A_i^T \\
}$$
and use a colon to denote the Frobenius product
$$\eqalign{
X:Y &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ij}Y_{ij} \;=\; \trace{X^TY} \\
X:X &= \frob{X}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
X:Y &= Y:X \;=\; Y^T:X^T \\
\LR{XY}:Z &= X:\LR{ZY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TZ} \\
}$$
You want the gradient of the following scalar function
$$\eqalign{
\p &= \LR{ABCe_r}^T \LR{B^TA^Te_i} \\
  &= e_r^T\LR{C^TB^TA^TB^TA^T}e_i \\
  &= \LR{e_re_i^T}:\LR{C^TB^TA^TB^TA^T} \\
  &= \LR{e_re_i^T}:\LR{C^TB^TXB^TX} \\
  &= \LR{BCe_re_i^T}:\LR{XB^TX} \\
}$$
First calculate the differential and the gradient wrt $X$
$$\eqalign{
d\p &= \LR{BCe_re_i^T}:\LR{XB^TdX+dX\,B^TX} \\
  &= \LR{BX^TBCe_re_i^T + BCe_re_i^TX^TB}:dX \\
  &= \LR{BABCe_re_i^T + BCe_re_i^TAB}:dX \\
\grad{\p}{X}
  &= \LR{BABCe_re_i^T + BCe_re_i^TAB} \;\equiv\; G \\
}$$
Then the gradient wrt $x_k\,$ is
$\;{\large\grad{\p}{x_k}} = Ge_k$

---

Note that $\p$ is the $(r,i)$ component of the matrix
$$ F = C^TB^TA^TB^TA^T $$